# Any way to control OAuth tokens based on IP ranges

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

we're providing an OAuth app accessing the Microsoft 365 services based on the Graph API.

Some customers want to allow access only within designated IP ranges.

When I tried to apply conditional access for IP control, however, I faced the following problem:

1. If the scopes don't include `openid`, conditional access doesn't apply at all.
2. Once an access token has been issued, the conditional access settings can no longer restrict the use of the token (for example, the token can be even outside the designated IP range).

Is there any solution for these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address is not a factor in the token.  Consider that your app requires *both* an access token as well as an incoming request that us from a specific IP range.  You can reject the request for either reason.